# Change only the extension of a file

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting, rename, mv

I am working on a simple shell script to change a file `one.PDF` to `one.pdf`. I have this file stored in a folder called Task1.

My script is in the same directory as Task1. Called `Shell1.sh` When I run it Task1 becomes Task1.pdf but the file inside one.PDF doesn't change. I need it the other way around but nothing I try seems to work I keep alternating between a syntax error, mv not being able to move because a resource is busy or just renaming the directory.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
#shebang for bourne shell execution
echo "Hello this is task 1"
 #Initial prompt used for testing to see if script ran
#/rename .* .pdf *.pdf // doesnt work

#loop to iterate through each file in current directory and rename
for file in Task1;
do
        mv "$file" "${file%.PDF}.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use globbing to get the filenames:

```
for file in Task1/*; do mv ...; done
```

For precision, only match the files ending in `.PDF`:

```
for file in Task1/*.PDF; do mv ...; done
```

More precise, make sure we are dealing with files, not directories:

```
for file in Task1/*.PDF; do [ -f "$file" ] && mv ...; done
```

---

As a side note, your parameter expansion pattern is fine.

Comment: @OP re: `for` and globbing, there seems to be a conceptual misunderstanding. `for` really only works on a set of strings, separated by the value of the variable `$IFS`. It does not do any logic (like reading the content of a folder) by itself. That's what `Task1/*` does, triggering the shell to do the hard work.

Comment: applying the first and second lines did the job. But if I add a new file `.three.PDF` for some reason the script ignores it. I think it's because the dot makes it hidden. But I don't know how to make my loop access it. Any advice?

Comment: @KazRodgers Set the `dotglob` option: `shopt -s dotglob`

Comment: I see. `shopt` lets you tweak the built in behavior `-s` is an option to affect the built in names. and `dot glob` contains all the strings that start with a dot. Geez I probably would have never found that on my own. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

Aside from basic shell commands, on most Lunux distributions there is a nice tool `rename` that can do the job of renaming multiple files in single command:

```
rename 's/PDF/pdf/' Task1/*
```

Here is a nice article about it: [Rename – A Command Line Tool For Renaming Multiple Files in Linux](http://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/).

Comment: Careful, some distributions have a `rename` that is a completely different command.

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution's `rename` is the C command from util-linux (e.g. Arch Linux):

`rename PDF pdf Task1/*PDF`

This will work unless your PDF files contain the string "PDF" somewhere other than the end, e.g. `example_PDF_file.PDF`.